# How to auto create or generate random ID (quiz_id) with 6 numeric on CI

Tags: sql, database, codeigniter

I would like to have random ID recorded in database when I create or post a quiz. So far, I still manually edit the ID in 6 numeric.

This image is where ID is manually edited. When I created a new quiz, the ID increases by one number at the end such as 107843, 107844, 107845 and so on.

[manual ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yClb7.jpg)